# List mount points in C++ on Linux without using /proc/mounts, /etc/fstab, system() or popen()

Tags: c++, c, linux, mount-point

I am looking for a solution to get the list of all `tmpfs` mount points available on my Linux system and I need to get it from a C/C++ program.
I need a generic solution that is not distro dependent.
I don't want to access `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/fstab`.
I don't want to use a `system()` or `popen()`.

Is there another way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you want to do those particular things?

Comment: Find a command that lists these mount points, and then go get the source to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `mount` implements this is to read `/etc/mtab` - `strace mount` is the fastest way to verify this if you don't have the source at hand. But as `/etc/mtab` is updated by mount/umount, and `/proc/mounts` is managed by the kernel itself, `/proc/mounts` is the better idea of the 2, and it's there on every linux system, independent of distro (hmm, maybe my Suse 4.4.2 which dates back to 1996 is an exception).

Or, if you want to be portable to non-linux Unixes, use the [getmntent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent) family of functions - but as the manual page states, other unixes have functions with the same name perform differently from the linux implementation, so while your code may *compile* on non-linux unixes, it won't neccesarily *work correctly* there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my solution needs only to work on linux.

I ruled out fstab, because I needed to mount my partition on the fly.

As for /proc/mounts, that was my first idea, but one told me that /proc was aimed at first to manage only processes and as it became bigger and bigger they was discussions about moving some elements somewhere else in the future.

So I was not sure that it was a safe solution in the long run.

I didn't know the existence of mtab, I think it could do the trick.

Thanks,
Charles.